# Custom java Graphics.drawLine() equation?

Tags: java, graphics, awt, line

I'm writing a custom class of my own to draw lines and points the way I want to, but I'm having an issue of graphing lines. I've got an `ArrayList` of a class I wrote extending `java.awt.Point`, and when I call the method to draw the line, I'd like to first just add them to the arraylist, to be rendered when I want them to.

I have the end point, and the start point of the line, but I don't know how to get the slope, or get all the points along it either. I'd like to know how to do this, but in code.

Comment: I think need supply a picture of what you are trying to do?  Are you trying to draw a curved line?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've just got an ArrayList of points, and want those points when rendered to be the equivalent of Graphics.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2)

Comment: So get the first point and the last point, using there x/y properties, draw the line...or start with the first element and in a loop, skip every second point